# Reusing layer weights in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, autoencoder, tf-slim

I am using tf.slim to implement an autoencoder. I's fully convolutional with the following architecture:

```
[conv, outputs = 1] => [conv, outputs = 15] => [conv, outputs = 25] =>
=> [conv_transpose, outputs = 25] => [conv_transpose, outputs = 15] => 
[conv_transpose, outputs = 1]
```

It has to be fully convolutional and I cannot do pooling (limitations of the larger problem). I want to use tied weights, so

```
encoder_W_3 = decoder_W_1_Transposed
```

(so the weights of the first decoder layer are the ones of the last encoder layer, transposed).

If I reuse weights the regular way tfslim lets you reuse them, i.e. reuse = True and then just provide the scope name of the layer you want to reuse, I get size issue:

```
ValueError: Trying to share variable cnn_block_3/weights, but specified shape (21, 11, 25, 25) and found shape (21, 11, 15, 25).
```

This makes sense, if you do not transpose the weights of the previous model. Does anyone have an idea on how I can transpose those weights?

PS: I know this is very abstract and hand-waving, but I am working with a custom api, on top of tfslim, so I can't post code examples here.

Comment: As I know, weights in Tensorflow have shape as `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`. I suppose you have the same filter size for each layer, so when you transpose the weights, there should be a correspondance for decoders and coders? e.g., `[outputs=1] => [outputs=15]` can be only used by `[outputs=15]=>[outputs=1]`. From the error message, I guess that `15=>25` was assigned to `25=>25`. But when the numbers of weights of these two layers are different , how can they be shared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone have an idea on how I can transpose those weights?

Transposition is simple:

```
new_weights = tf.transpose(weights, perm=[0, 1, 3, 2])
```

will swap the last two axes.

However, as @Seven mentioned, that wouldn't be enough to address the error, as the total number of weights changed.

Comment: This works well for a transposition of an existing variable. However, with tf.slim, the kernel weights are hidden behind an abstraction - so reusing (and transposing) them should be done via another, as yet unknown, method...